# How to move the items from one listbox to another listbox

Tags: vba, vb6

Using VB6

In a form, 2 listbox name as list1, list2 and 4 buttons name >, >>, <, <<

```
I want to add the list1 selected items to list2
I want to remove the selected items from list2 to list1
```

How to do this.

Need Vb6 code Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, your approach will be to loop through the index values of all items in your source ListBox.  If you're moving all items on the ListBox then for each item you'd call the [AddItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244161%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) method on your destination ListBox (using the index value to retrieve the text of the current item on your source ListBox).  You would then call the ListBox [RemoveItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244161%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) method to remove the same item from your source ListBox.

If you're moving only selected items, then you'd still loop through all index values but you'd use the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445676%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) property for each item on the source ListBox to determine if the item is selected.  If it is, use the steps above to move the item.

Specifics on what you need to do varies however, depending on how you've set a few properties on your ListBoxes.  A resource you'll find useful is [the discussion on ListBoxes](http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch09/09-14-Listboxes.htm) over at thevbprogrammer.com.  Look at the section *Example: Adding and Removing Items with Two ListBoxes*;  it includes examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To Add in List2 From List1 in VBA

```
Private Sub CMDAddOne_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_cmdAdd_Click
    If Me.List1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
        Me.List2.AddItem (Me.List1.ItemData(Me.List1.ListIndex))
    End If

    Exit_cmdAdd_Click:
      Exit Sub

    Err_cmdAdd_Click:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_cmdAdd_Click
End Sub
```

To Remove From List2

```
If Me.List2.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    Me.List2.RemoveItem Me.List2.ListIndex
 End If
```