# Take list box selection, add value to other list box without allowing duplicates

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

I have two list boxes on a form I am making. The first list box is linked to a table with various company names. The goal I am after is after double clicking a companies name, the value is inserted in the second list box.

It worked fine until I tried to add code to prevent duplicates from appearing in the second list box, so you couldn't accidentally insert the same company twice. I have tried several different iterations, but with no luck. Anyone able to help with this one? My end goal would be for a `msgbox` to pop up alerting the user that duplicates are not allowed.

```
Private Sub ContractorLstbx_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    Dim ID As Long
    Dim Contractor As String
    
    For Each newItem In Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemsSelected
        For j = 0 To Me.SelectedContractorLst.ListCount - 1
            If (Me!ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem).Column(1) = Me.SelectedContractorLst.ItemData(j).Column(1)) Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If found = False Then
            ID = Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem)
            Me.SelectedContractorLst.AddItem ContractorLstbx!.ItemData(newItem).Column(0) & ";" & Me!ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem).Column(1)
            
        End If
        found = False
    Next newItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not remove the selected items from the first listbox?

Comment: I suppose that could work and would probably be simpler in the long run. That wouldn't mess with the table would it? I am new to this, so don't fully understand everything and am learning as I go.

Comment: I don't know - I guess it depends how your listbox is set up.  I'm not an Access person so maybe someone else can chime in...

Comment: Review https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6326, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa260425(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp8wJ-r-xSI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the items from one listbox to another listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102735/how-to-move-the-items-from-one-listbox-to-another-listbox)

Comment: Your code seems to be correct and should function but I notice one point in the check line `If (Me!ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem).Column(1) = Me.SelectedContractorLst.ItemData(j).Column(1)) Then` try to replace the "!" after first Me with "." as I guess this will give null value as it tries to call record value not the list item value so it will never go inside. Try to put break point on this line and check values in condition and you will get the problem cause.

Comment: @mamadsp I made that change and now it is throwing a compile error. ```Type-declaration character does not match declared data type``` on this line of code. ```Me.SelectedContractorLst.AddItem ContractorLstbx!.ItemData(newItem).Column(0) & ";" & Me!ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem).Column(1)```

Comment: @Tmyers Sorry this line of code need to be modified the same as well. Here is the modified and you can copy paste directly:
`Me.SelectedContractorLst.AddItem ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem).Column(0) & ";" & Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemData(newItem).Column(1)`

Comment: @mamadsp Thank you for your response (and sorry for the wait). I made that change, and now it is throwing an ```object required``` error. I have been researching this all morning to try and figure out why, and have not had much luck with a solution that fixes it. I dont understand why it would be throwing that error.

Comment: @Tmyers You are correct. I didn't revise the syntax in your code. The ItemData property doesn't have the Column property that's why you recieve the object required error. You need to use Column property of the list box directly. I will post solution with the new full code that you can use directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the full code for your solution. I tried it on test sample and working fine. just copy and paste the code. If you need your comparison to be case sensitive (I mean A <> a) then use `Option Compare Binary` as in my code below. If it is required to be case insensitive (A = a) just leave the default `Option Compare Database` or better force it using `Option Compare Text`

```
Option Compare Binary

Private Sub ContractorLstbx_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    Dim ID As Long
    Dim Contractor As String

    For i = 0 To Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemsSelected.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To Me.SelectedContractorLst.ListCount - 1
            If (Me.ContractorLstbx.Column(1, Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemsSelected(i)) = Me.SelectedContractorLst.Column(1, j)) Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If found = False Then
            ID = Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemData(Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemsSelected(i))
            Me.SelectedContractorLst.AddItem (ContractorLstbx.Column(0, Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemsSelected(i)) & ";" & Me.ContractorLstbx.Column(1, Me.ContractorLstbx.ItemsSelected(i)))
        
        End If
        found = False
    Next i
End Sub
```